# How do you select an index from a series of numbers in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am working on a project on "substitution Cipher"

I have gotten my "key", which are a series of numbers something like:

```
a = {12,31,42,1,23,-12,...}
```

my plain text is "abcdef" , then `ord (plain text) = {97,98,99,100,101,102}`

basically what I want to do is add the corresponding key to my plain text.

That is, when the plain text is `"a"`, it's the 0th letter, therefore I'd like to add 0th key (i.e 12) to my ord "a".   When the plain text is `"b"`, it's the 1th letter, so I am adding 1th key to this plain text in order to get my cipher text. And so on.

How do I start on this?

Comment: You are using a set notation, which means there is no ordering. Did you mean to use lists or tuples instead?

Comment: Yes! I didn't know the parenthesis mattered that much. Now i get it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to pair up the elements of several lists:

```
key = (12, 31, 42, 1, 23, -12)  # a tuple
inputstring = 'abcdef'

for char, keyval in zip(map(ord, inputstring), key):
    # do something with the char ordinal and the key value.
```

This *does* assume that your key is at least as long as the input string.

If your input key is of a fixed length and you want to repeat using it, you can use the [`itertools.cycle()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeatedly loop over the key and pair up the key values with the string, until you run out of characters in the string:

```
from itertools import cycle

key = (12, 31, 42, 1, 23, -12)  # a tuple
inputstring = 'abcdefghijkl'

for char, keyval in zip(map(ord, inputstring), cycle(key)):
    # do something with the char ordinal and the key value.
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> key = (12, 31, 42, 1, 23, -12) 
>>> inputstring = 'abcdefghijkl'
>>> for char, keyval in zip(map(ord, inputstring), cycle(key)):
...     print char, keyval
... 
97 12
98 31
99 42
100 1
101 23
102 -12
103 12
104 31
105 42
106 1
107 23
108 -12
```

Here the key values repeat as they are paired up with the ordinals of the input string.

Comment: Hmm...Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, input string can be shorter or longer than  the key. But len(key) is always fixed at 26

Comment: Good stuff, but a bit too advanced... They're really going to impress their prof with that.

Comment: Yes...This is my first python project ever...Your codes look too advanced and complicated for me and that seems impossible for me to understand. but anyways I appreciate your time.

Comment: @user2983167: `zip()` combines two lists; the only 'advanced' stuff here is the `itertools.cycle()` call, really.

Comment: @user2983167: The `map(ord, inputstring)` can be replaced by `inputstring` and then using `ord` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn pointed out, you are using `set` notion (`{}`) which doesnt maintain order, you might want to use list notation (`[]`)  or tuple notation (`()`). Now, we can use enumerate on the string to get the index and the corresponding character in the string. We can use the same index on the cipher table to get the corresponding number.

```
a = [12,31,42,1,23,-12]
plainString, lenA = "abcdef", len(a)
for index, char in enumerate(plainString):
    print char, ord(char), a[index % lenA]
```

**Output**

```
a 97 12
b 98 31
c 99 42
d 100 1
e 101 23
f 102 -12
```

Comment: Given that the key is shorter than the input, you might want to use `a[index % len(a)]` instead.

Comment: @thg435 Thanks :) OP might have forgotten to mention this in the question.

Comment: Hmm...I have encountered a problem which it said "int" object is not subscriptable.  I think the error meant "a[index % lenA]" , my a is exactly like what you have told , a bunch of numbers.  Too be clear, if i prind my a , it shows 26 numbers which are my keys.